# setText does nothing

Tags: android, android-button

```
public class gameHomeScreen extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    public static Socket socket;
    private Button button;
    private PrintWriter printwriter;
    private BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    String serverReply = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_home_screen);
        if(login.client!=null){
            socket = login.client;
        }else if(signup.client!=null){
            socket = signup.client;
        }
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        button.setText("Waiting...");
        SendMessage sm = new SendMessage();
        sm.execute();
        while(!serverReply.equals("game_found")) {
            //do nothing
        }
        Intent i = new Intent(this, InGame.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();


    }
    private class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                printwriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                printwriter.println("game_queue"); // write the message to output stream

                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                do {
                    serverReply = bufferedReader.readLine();
                }while(!serverReply.equals("game_found"));


            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        }
    }
}
```

This line of code doesnt work :

```
button.setText("Waiting...");
```

I've tried using handlers and using the `UIThread` but nothing works. The text only changes for half a second to "waiting..." whenever a game is found though, its pretty strange...

Comment: as long as you keep the UI thread occupied, the UI won´t update. You should return from the Button event handler as soon as possible!!

Comment: as mentioned above you are lagging your UI thread with while loop. You can't freez UI thread,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're hanging the UI thread:

```
    while(!serverReply.equals("game_found")) {
        //do nothing
    }
```

Don't do this on the `onClick` method. This method is called from the UI thread and you're locking it up (which might also give you an ANR).

Comment: Thanks! I solved my problem by making a goInGame(); method that opens up the new intent. goInGame() gets called inside the AsyncTask right after a game is found. onClick only changes the button text and executes the asynctask now!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the loop from `onClick`:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    button.setText("Waiting...");
    SendMessage sm = new SendMessage();
    sm.execute();
    //while(!serverReply.equals("game_found")) {
    //    do nothing
    //}
    //Intent i = new Intent(this, InGame.class);
    //startActivity(i);
    //finish();
}
```

And start the intent in your `AsyncTask`:

```
private class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    // ...

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        Intent i = new Intent(this, InGame.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}
```